# Separating geographical data strings in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I'm working with [QECW data from BLS](https://www.bls.gov/web/cewdat.supp.toc.htm) and would like to make the geographical data included more useful. I want to split the column "area_title" into different columns - one with the area's name, one with the level of the area, and one with the state.

I got a good start using separate:

```
qecw <- qecw %>% separate(area_title, c("county", "geography level", "state"))
```

The problem is that there's a variety of ways the geographical data are arranged into strings that makes them not uniform enough to cleanly separate. The area_title column includes names in formats that separate pretty cleanly, like:

```
area_title

Alabama -- Statewide
Autauga County, Alabama
```

which splits pretty well into

```
county    geography level    state

Alabama   Statewide          NA
Autauga   County             Alabama
```

but this breaks down for  cases like:

```
area_title

Aleutians West Census Area, Alaska
Chattanooga-Cleveland-Dalton TN-GA-AL CSA
U.S. Combined statistical Areas, combined
```

as well as any states, counties or other place names that have more than one word.

I can go case-by-case to fix these, but I would appreciate a more efficient solution.

The exact data I'm using is "2019.q1-q3 10 10 Total, all industries," available at the link under "Current year quarterly data grouped by industry".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up with this:

I can get a place name by selecting a substring of area_title with everything to the left of the first comma:

```
qecw <- qecw %>% mutate(location = sub(",.*","", qecw$area_title))
```

Then I have a series of nested if_else statements to create a location type:

```
 mutate(`Location Type` = 
           if_else(str_detect(area_title, "Statewide"), "State", 
           if_else(str_detect(area_title, "County"), "County",
           if_else(str_detect(area_title, "CSA"), "CSA",
           if_else(str_detect(area_title, "MSA"), "MSA",
           if_else(str_detect(area_title, "MicroSA"), "MicroSA",
           if_else(str_detect(area_title, "Undefined"), "Undefined",
                                                           "other")))))))
```

This isn't a complete answer; I think I'm still missing some location types, and I haven't come up with a good way to extract state names yet.